# Google API/Celery(with django/redis)- Function with api call works as a normal func, add .delay() to add it to asynchronous task queue,get SSL error

Tags: django, asynchronous, redis, google-api, celery

Update: I have found that celery is even working fine with other api calls, just not the google api, so it makes me think somehow google api and celery are not compatible or some setting needs to be changed?

I have celery setup fine in that it works for simple tasks like a hello world (calling hello_world.delay() in django views there is no problem).

I created another more complicated function that involves making many calls to a an api to retrieve data to update the database. Just calling this function without celery (update_comments()) there is no problem, and the database gets updated(takes around 15 seconds or so...that is why I want to use celery). Currently the function makes dozens of calls to the api to update the model.

The problem is once I add .delay() to make it a celery task. I get the below errors (maxretry ssl error).  I know I have celery setup correctly for basic tasks as it works fine for a basic hello world function, but not this more complicated function with many api calls.  I can't figure out why there is this disparity or if there is any setting I am supposed to change because I have an api call.  Currently just running on dev.

Tasks

```
    @task()
def update_comments():
    for channel in Channel.objects.all():
        search_url='https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads'
        params1={
             'part': 'replies,snippet',
             'allThreadsRelatedToChannelId': channel.channel,
              'searchTerms': '#vi',
             'maxResults': 100,
             'order': 'time',
             'key' : settings.YOUTUBE_API_DATA_KEY
        }
        params2={
             'part': 'replies,snippet',
             'allThreadsRelatedToChannelId': channel.channel,
              'searchTerms': '#faq',
             'maxResults': 100,
             'order': 'time',
             'key' : settings.YOUTUBE_API_DATA_KEY
        }
        params3={
             'part': 'replies,snippet',
             'allThreadsRelatedToChannelId': channel.channel,
              'searchTerms': '#save',
             'maxResults': 100,
             'order': 'time',
             'key' : settings.YOUTUBE_API_DATA_KEY
        }
        r1=requests.get(search_url, params=params1)
        r2=requests.get(search_url, params=params2)
        r3=requests.get(search_url, params=params3)
        rj1=r1.json()
        rj2=r2.json()
        rj3=r3.json()

        a=1
        b=1
        c=1
        for x in range(0, len(rj1['items'])):
            if a ==1:
                reply_count=rj1['items'][x]['snippet']['totalReplyCount']
                for y in range (0, reply_count):
                    if rj1['items'][x]['replies']['comments'][y]['snippet']['channelId']==channel.channel:
                        if Comments.objects.filter(question=rj1['items'][x]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'], answer=rj1['items'][x]['replies']['comments'][y]['snippet']['textOriginal'], channel=channel, key="#vi").exists():
                            a=2
                            break
                        else:
                            #get out of for loop
                            new_comment=Comments(question=rj1['items'][x]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'], answer=rj1['items'][x]['replies']['comments'][y]['snippet']['textOriginal'], channel=channel, key="#vi")
                            new_comment.save()
                            break
                    else:
                        continue
                    break
            else:
                break


        for x in range(0, len(rj2['items'])):
            if b == 1:
                reply_count=rj2['items'][x]['snippet']['totalReplyCount']
                for y in range (0, reply_count):
                    if rj2['items'][x]['replies']['comments'][y]['snippet']['channelId']==channel.channel:
                        if Comments.objects.filter(question=rj2['items'][x]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'], answer=rj2['items'][x]['replies']['comments'][y]['snippet']['textOriginal'], channel=channel, key="#faq").exists():
                            b=2
                            break
                        else:
                            #get out of for loop
                            new_comment=Comments(question=rj2['items'][x]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'], answer=rj2['items'][x]['replies']['comments'][y]['snippet']['textOriginal'], channel=channel, key="#faq")
                            new_comment.save()
                            break
                    else:
                        continue
                    break
            else:
                break


        for x in range(0, len(rj3['items'])):
            if c == 1:
                reply_count=rj3['items'][x]['snippet']['totalReplyCount']
                for y in range (0, reply_count):
                    if rj3['items'][x]['replies']['comments'][y]['snippet']['channelId']==channel.channel:
                        if Comments.objects.filter(question=rj3['items'][x]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'], answer=rj3['items'][x]['replies']['comments'][y]['snippet']['textOriginal'], channel=channel, key="#save").exists():
                            c=2
                            break
                        else:
                            #get out of for loop
                            new_comment=Comments(question=rj3['items'][x]['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textOriginal'], answer=rj3['items'][x]['replies']['comments'][y]['snippet']['textOriginal'], channel=channel, key="#save")
                            new_comment.save()
                            break
                    else:
                        continue
                    break
            else:
                break
```

Views

```
def tes(request):
    update_comments.delay()
```

Settings

> CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0' BROKER_TRANSPORT =
>   'redis' CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'

ERROR

```
 ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task todo.tasks.update_comments[d368d4eb-d149-4461-a829-e8372cb9a6a5] raised unexpected: ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=replies%2Csnippet&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UC_EyncGJh2QuQHhcfuDWL6g&searchTerms=%23vi&maxResults=100&order=time&key=xx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x109380cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 334, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x109380cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=replies%2Csnippet&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UC_EyncGJh2QuQHhcfuDWL6g&searchTerms=%23vi&maxResults=100&order=time&key=xx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x109380cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/src/todo/tasks.py", line 49, in update_comments
    r1=requests.get(search_url, params=params1)
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=replies%2Csnippet&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UC_EyncGJh2QuQHhcfuDWL6g&searchTerms=%23vi&maxResults=100&order=time&key=xx (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x109380cd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))
```

Comment: I should note that any simple api call to that api is not working when it is a task, but works perfectly when no .delay() is added

Comment: UPDATE: It works with other apis, but not the specifc google api I am working with.