# Google Drive API in Celery Task is Failing

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-drive-api, celery, google-api-python-client

Latest Update:`http` request within task are working but not `https`.

I am trying to use Celery Task to Upload Files to Google Drive, once the files have been Uploaded to Local Web Server for Backup.
I saw multiple question asking similar things .I cannot make Google API work in a celery task but it works when I run it without `delay()`.The questions didn't recieve any answers.
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58667752/google-api-celerywith-django-redis-function-with-api-call-works-as-a-normal-f) where @chucky struggling like me.

**Implementation and Information:**

- Server: Django Development Server (localhost)
- Celery: Working with RabbitMQ
- Database: Postgres
- GoogleDriveAPI: V3

> I was able to get credentials and token for accessing drive files and
> display first ten files,If the quickstart file is run separately.
> Google Drive API [Quickstart.py](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/master/drive/quickstart/quickstart.py)

Running this `Quickstart.py` shows files and folder list of drive.

> So I added the same code with all included imports in `tasks.py` task
> name `create_upload_folder()` to test whether task will work and show
> list of files.

I am running it with a Ajax Call but i keep getting this error.
[image: Error Console]

So tracing back show that this above error occurs due to:
[image: TracebackError]

Root of the Error is :

```
[2021-07-13 21:10:03,979: WARNING/MainProcess] 

[2021-07-13 21:10:04,052: ERROR/MainProcess] Task create_upload_folder[2463ad5b-4c7c-4eba-b862-9417c01e8314] raised unexpected: ServerNotFoundError('Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\repos\vuetransfer\vuenv\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1346, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "f:\repos\vuetransfer\vuenv\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1136, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
  File "f:\repos\vuetransfer\vuenv\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 257, in connect
    if socket_connect(fd, address):
  File "f:\repos\vuetransfer\vuenv\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 40, in socket_connect
    err = descriptor.connect_ex(address)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is with using httplib2 with python3 or some other complication even though google_client_api for python says it is fully supported you have some problems with requests.Atleast the problem is there for me with python3 on Windows.
Which after a lot of research i found that falling back to python2 is a solution but another one can be using `httplib2shim` after creating a credentials for your service and before **`.build()`** for your service you need to call

```
.
. 
httplib2shim.patch()
    service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=creds)
```

This will solve the issue of httplib2 not able to find the `www.googleapis.com`

Answer (score 1):

It's failing on the name resolution (can't find the IP of `www.googleapis.com`) because most likely it can't contact a DNS server that has the IP (or can't contact *any* DNS server).

Make sure you have your DNS server properly set up or if you are behind a corporate proxy/VPN that you're using it.

You can verify it working by fetching the IPs manually:

```
nslookup www.googleapis.com
```

```
$ nslookup www.googleapis.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.googleapis.com
Address: 172.217.23.234
Name:   www.googleapis.com
Address: 216.58.201.74
Name:   www.googleapis.com
Address: 172.217.23.202
Name:   www.googleapis.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4014:80c::200a
Name:   www.googleapis.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4014:800::200a
Name:   www.googleapis.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4014:80d::200a
```

In case you can fetch the IPs manually there's a connectivity problem  with Python itself not being aware of the proxies (that might have been set up on your PC) and for this try to use:

- `http_proxy=http://your.proxy:port`
- `https_proxy=http://your.proxy:port`

in the environment or as a command prefix or directly in the HTTP client configuration `httplib2` uses.

Comment: Yes,I am able to fetch IPs manually even when running api within the view works.
Once async task is created the error is there. https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build This is being used to create the service. `build()` have `http` attribute which i think is using `httplib2`.
I am not sure what to set as a proxy and how to work with httplib2 config and where it is. I would need some help doing that.